# Find unknown vector knowing products of its subsets

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, nonlinear-system

I would like to solve the following problem. I have a $N\times 1 $ complex vector, for example with $N=6$:

$$v=(a \; b \; c\; d \; e \;f)^T$$

and its complex conjugate

$$\bar{v}=(\bar{a} \; \bar{b} \; \bar{c}\; \bar{d}\; \bar{e} \;\bar{f})^T$$

I can access any value of the product of a subset of $v$ with the complementary subset of $\bar{v}$. For example:

$$(a+b+c)(\bar{d} + \bar{e} + \bar{f})=\alpha_1\\ (a+b+d)(\bar{c} + \bar{e}+\bar{f})=\alpha_3\\ (a+c+d)(\bar{b} + \bar{e}+\bar{f})=\alpha_2\\...$$

In each case, the subsets are of size $N/2$, and each element appears only once. If we consider the elements of $\bar{v}$ as unknowns as well, we have $2N$ unknowns, and if I'm correct there are $N$ choose $N/2$ (or $N!/(N/2!)^2$) such products. Therefore we can produce enough equations to close the system starting from $N=6$.

Is there a general way to find $v$ form the $\alpha_i$?

I would like to find a way to automatise this in code for any $N$, where the list of $\alpha_i$ is given, with for each $\alpha_i$ some information encoding the corresponding subset (for example a vector of 1 and 0 indicating which elements are taken from $v$ and which from $\bar{v}$, respectively). I tried to express the problem in a compact algebraic way but I couldn't put it in a form that would lend itself to common functions (I work on Matlab).

Comment: Not sure I am following. Suppose $(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(1,1,1,1,1,1)$.  Then all your products are $3\times 3=9$.   Now suppose $(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)$.  Then all your products are $(-3)\times (-3)=9$.   Seems to me that that is a counterexample to what you want, right?  Or have I misunderstood the goal.  More generally, if you replace $\vec v$ by $-\vec v$, none of your products change.

Comment: If you find that example too trivial, try $\vec v = (1,1,1,1,1,2)$.  Then every product is $3\times 4=12$.  But this would be true for any placement of the single $2$.

Comment: Yes actually the solution is only defined within a complex number of modulus 1. Or even worse given the second example...

Comment: And, of course, the  $\vec v = \frac 2{\sqrt 3}\times (1,1,1,1,1,1)$  also has the property that ll your sums are $12$, so you really can't say much.